# How to remove a set of words from a character variable?

Tags: sas

I want to compare two columns that have people names. I realized that many names differ mainly because they have words like "DA", "DO", "DE" "DAS" "DOS" (they are Portuguese names). I want to create new variables without these words.

So, for example, I have the following dataset:

```
data have;
  input NAMES $50. ;
datalines;
MARIA DO CARMO SILVA
FRANCISCO DE ASSIS DETERO
MARIA DAS DORES ENTADAS
ANTONIO CALCADOS DOS SANTOS 
JULIA SILVA DA SILVA GOMEDA
FELIDA DA DAMADOS DOS DOSOMEDE DE DEIXADA
;
```

And I want to obtain the following:

```
data want;
  input NAMES $50. ;
datalines;
MARIA CARMO SILVA
FRANCISCO ASSIS DETERO
MARIA DORES ENTADAS
ANTONIO CALCADOS SANTOS 
JULIA SILVA SILVA GOMEDA
FELIDA DAMADOS DOSOMEDE DEIXADA
;
```

What have I tried? Well, I tried the following, but it didnt work:

```
data want;
set have;  
NEW_NAMES = substr(compress(NAMES, ' da do de dos das '), 2);
RUN;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is the best way to go about this. You can nest a bunch of `transtrn` functions together, but it wouldn't be as elegant. `prxchange` will convert matching words into another word with the format `s/regex here/new word here/regex options`.

We need to use the regex `\b(da | do | de | dos |das )\b`. [Test it out here](https://regex101.com/r/pfGWSy/1).

`prxchange('s/\b(da |do |de |dos |das )\b//i', -1, names)` says to convert the words `da` , `do` , `de` , `dos` , and `das`  into an empty string using case-insensitive matching (`/i` option). We add a space to each word so we do not introduce double-spaces into the final string by removing the word, but this could be solved with the `compbl` function if we did not do this. We replace all matches in the string with the `-1` argument.

```
data want;
    set have;
    names = prxchange('s/\b(da |do |de |dos |das )\b//i', -1, names);
run;
```

```
NAMES
MARIA CARMO SILVA
FRANCISCO ASSIS DETERO
MARIA DORES ENTADAS
ANTONIO CALCADOS SANTOS
JULIA SILVA SILVA GOMEDA
FELIDA DAMADOS DOSOMEDE DEIXADA
```